# why do we have two if statements in arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

in the following code dont we use an 'else' statement after the 'if' statement in this case?

```
// These constants won't change
cont int sensorPin = A0;
const int ledPin = 9;

// Variables
int sensorValue = 0;
int sensorMin = 1023;
int sensorMax = 0;

void setup() {
    // Turn on LED to signal the start of the calibration period
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT):
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

    while(millis() < 5000) {
        sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

        if(sensorValue > sensorMax) {
            sensorMax = sensorValue;
        }

        if(sensorValue < sensorMin) {
            sensorMin = sensorValue; 
        } 
    }
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

Why did the arduino example present 2 'ifs'? please help me understand!

Thank you

Comment: `else` is optional in C and related C-like languages.

Comment: Please don't show an image of the code, include it **as text in the question** and format it as a code block using the `{}` tool of the editor field. The code does not use `else` because at least in the first loop cycle bothe conditions can be true.

Comment: Because the programmer felt like it.

Comment: Because "not greater than" is less than **or equal to**.  The code is omitting the comparison for equality.

Comment: Only the writer of the code knows the answer

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this code it is pretty easy to understand. Let's consider this:

We never read a sensor before, so both max and min are uninitialized (say, std::numeric_limits::min() and max()).

Sensor is read once.

Here we need to fill BOTH values, not one of them, because currently it does satisfy the invariant. Adding "else" would break that logic.

P.S. Also, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this website' rules and next time try to write questions that comply with them.

Comment: min and max are not uninitialized. they are 1023 and 0.we also do not have to fill both values. I don't get your point

Comment: In this code, they are not uninitialized. They are initialized with incorrect data that needs to change after first iteration of the cycle. Generally, when trying to find min and max value of any incoming data, putting "else" into the code is a mistake. In case you'll suddenly end up with a vector with a single element, code will break.

Comment: Here, min == 1023 and max == 0. When first value comes (say, 500), they need to be both equal 500. If "else" is added, max would become 500, but min would still be 1023, which is incorrect.

Comment: This would 100% be an issue for the first iteration of the cycle. Then, if after 500 comes 501, you miss min value again, it is still 1023. But it should have become 500 two iterations ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard algorithm for a running calculation of the minimum and maximum values, without having to store the values.

```
int minimum;
int maximum;
std::cin >> minimum;
maximum = minimum;
for (int i = 0; i < 4999; ++i)
{
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    if (value > maximum) maximum = value;
    if (value < minimum) minimum = value;
}
```

The posted code is finding the minimum and maximum values of a sensor for a given duration (again, without having to store the values).

Remember, the sensor is taking "real" measurements, not ideal.  Real measurements are not exact and can fluctuate.